# Excel table: Add only certain values (Oscar predictions ballot)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

So for tonight, me and friends made a spreadsheet with oscar nominations and predictions of winners. What I'm trying to achieve is that I just put a '1' or an 'x' or something behind the winner in that category, and whoever guessed it gets awarded one point. Like now it looks like this

```
Category    Player 1    Player 2    Player 3
Film 1        X
Film 2                               X
Film 3                     X       
Film 4
Film 5
```

Now, if Film 3 wins the award, I want player 2 to be have his score be updated by 1, and the other people be at the same score.
The way I am currently doing that is by entering a three formulas in three cells under each category, the formulas include the row, and are formatted like this: =IF((B5>0);1;0), where B5 would be an extra column in front of the movie where I put in a 1 if this movie wins. Therefore, if a predicted movie wins, the user will get a score of 1 in the cell under the category in the column of their name, and in the end I just do a SUM of all these cells, so we can see the overall score.

So kind of like this:

```
Category    Winning film    Player 1    Player 2    Player 3
Film 1                         X
Film 2                                                X
Film 3         1                            X       
Film 4
Film 5
Score:                         0            1         0
```

My question, is there a faster, smarter way to do this? Because this requires me to change 3 players times 24 categories is 72 cells that I need to manually enter the movie everyone predicted.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would make a summary section in another tab like this:

```
       A        B
    -------------------
   1|Player 1|  3     |
    -------------------
   2|Player 2|  2     |
    -------------------
   3|Player 3|  4     |
    -------------------
   4|Winner  |Player 3|
    -------------------
```

Then formula for for B1-B3 would be `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!B:B,Row(A1))` and the formula for the Winner would be `=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(MAX(B1:B3),B1:B3))`